# How to grow ESXI 6.0.0 VMFS 5.60 datastore beyond 2TB?

Tags: mbr, gpt, esxi

I hope that this is the right place to ask my question. I have an ESXI 6.0.0 host with a raid as datastore embracing 2.73TB. But I am only able to grow the datastore to 2TB. I already figured out, that it still uses MBR and that this is most likely the reason why I am not able to grow it beyond 2TB. From this [KB article](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=2058287) I figured understand that "You must use the vSphere Web Client to create or extend a VMDK beyond 2 TB" and then it would convert from MBR to GPT automatically. The problem is, I am using the free license and you can not manage those hosts witch the vSphere Web Client. So I wonder if it is possible to manually change from MBR to GPT via console? Is there any other way to grow the disk, do I need to buy a license? Thanks!

[image]

Here you can see that the total capacity is 2.73TB, if you hit "Increase" it does not offer me the raid.
[image]

Comment: I am confused.  What does creating a virtual disk larger then 2 TB have to do with creating a datastore that is larger then 2 TB?  Please edit your question to make it clear if your asking for an alternative method to creating a EFI compatible virtual hdd or you want to create a datastore that is larger then 2 TB.  You can use vmkfstools  to create the virtual hdd by the way, says so, right in the article you linked to.

Comment: Sorry if I have misused some terms, but as far as I understand, there is a hardware raid with 2.73TB, and thereon I currently have a datastore using 2TB, but I want it to use 2.73TB. The ESXI host is able to see that the hardware raid offers 2.73TB but I can not extend the datastore. That's my problem :). Hope things are more clear now.